# Symfony 3 | Custom constraints on CollectionType entities

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, constraints, custom-validators

I followed the documentation and was able to add custom constraints on many of my fields (http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

I'm figuring a problem with CollectionType field.
My custom constraint just check if user didn't tap multiple space in field (the constraint doesn't matter anyway).

**I have a Question form with a title and answers :**

```
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'    => AnswerType::class,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
```

**I have my constraint :**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsText extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'constraint_error';
}
```

**And my constraint validator :**

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsTextValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // It checks if user didn't had multiple space in field
        if (strlen(trim($value)) == 0) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

In my entities :

**Question:**

```
use XX\XXBundle\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert;    

class Question 
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @CustomAssert\ContainsText    
     */
    private $title;
    ...
}
```

**Answer :**

```
use XX\XXBundle\Validator\Constraints as CustomAssert; 

class Answer 
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @CustomAssert\ContainsText    
     */
    private $text;
    ...
}
```

In my form validation, if in Question title I tap many spaces, I get a form validation error with my "constraint_error" message => Everything is working.

But, if in Question answers text I tap many spaces, the form validation doesn't return any errors and my question is created with empty answers !

It seems that, if the field comes from a CollectionType, the custom asserts are ignored.

What I don't understand is, if i had a Assert (like @Assert\Blank(), not a custom one) on answer text, even if we are in a CollectionType, the assert is not ignored and I can't validate a form with a blank answer.

What did I miss here ? TY

Comment: I am a bit confused :) The title says `Symfony3` but the tag name says `symfony2`. In any case, the answers covers both ;)

Comment: Sorry my bad, this is Symfony 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which Symfony 2 version you use, but depending if that is pre 2.8 or  later you have different ways to tackle this:

### v2.8+ and v3.0+

Starting with `v2.8`, which I suspect you could be using given `AnswerType::class`, `cascade_validation` was deprecated. Instead, you need to applty `Valid` constraint, on you `Question::$answers` class member. Something like this:

```
class Question 
{
    /**
     * ... Other anotaions go here 
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $answers
}
```

### Pre v2.8:

You need to specify `cascade_validation` option:

```
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class)
    ->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'    => AnswerType::class,
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true // <========= THIS
        ));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I'm on Symfony 3, I didn't know I had to use @Assert\Valid() in order to not ignore my custom validators on CollectionType. TY Jovan Perovic !

Comment: Thank you guys for the question and the following answer. I trapped in the same situation and was unable to figure out what I did wrong!